# Changing my account on minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: My actual account]

[image: Files of my old account]

I already asked this question on g+, but nobody answered it, so it may look a stupid question, but I moved my minecraft account and I ask if by changing the name of my old files, will it makes my stuff from my old account. (my items, my pets etc.) be moved into my new account?
I just don't want to screw up everything that's why I'm asking.
If possible you can precise what's important to do while modifying all the files.
Thanks for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all your items change the name of the files, if your old name was Example1 and you changed it to Example2, you would have to rename Example1.dat to Example2.dat. change the name of every .dat file containing your old name. There might also be name data in the file so make sure to check inside the files. Use Notepad or I recommend Notepad++. You can download [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), The source code is available if you want it.

Comment: You don't need to post a new answer, just edit your old one.

Comment: I chose to delete the old one.